# Geofence event transition type is always -1 suddenly

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-geofence

We've had a working Geofencing system in our app that used to work just fine. Recently, I checked out a reported issue and found that all transition events seem to have a `-1` transition type which, according to the docs, means that *the intent specified in fromIntent(Intent) is not generated for a transition alert*.

I don't understand how that can be, though. We didn't change anything in our implementation and apart from that, the pending intent is triggered every time I trigger an enter/exit event, through the emulator's location setting.

Here's our flow:

```
// we create a geo-fence from an FCM notification payload
    override fun createGeofenceFromEvent(geoEventData: GeoEventData) =
        Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(geoEventData.id)
            .setCircularRegion(
                geoEventData.latitude,
                geoEventData.longitude,
                geoEventData.radius
            )
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build()

// then we add it to the client (it's added successfully) like so
    override fun addGeofenceToClient(geofence: Geofence) {
        App.instance.geofencingClient.addGeofences(
            getGeofencingRequest(geofence),
            App.instance.geofencePendingIntent
        ).run {
            addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(tag, "Geofence with id ${geofence.requestId} added to client!")
            }
            addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(tag, "Failed to add geofence with id ${geofence.requestId} to client!")
                it.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

// here's the pending intent declaration
    val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(appContext, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    }
```

Then in our `GeofenceBroadcastReceiver` class it always logs `-1` now when using:

```
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (!checkForNotificationUserChoice(context)) return
        val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent!!)
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            val errorMessage = GeofenceStatusCodes
                .getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.errorCode)
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
            return
        }
        val geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition
        Log.e(TAG,"$geofenceTransition")
        ...
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here? I've made sure that I'm testing on an emulator with Google Play Services & APIs enabled, that GPS/Location is enabled and that location updates work, that the “Always” option is enabled for location tracking, etc.

To sum up:

1. Geo-fence payloads reach the app successfully through FCM
2. Geo-fences are created and added to the client successfully as well
3. Enter/exit events triggered by changing the emulator's
   location also seem to be received by the system correctly
4. BUT, the pending intent that handles the transport of the geo-fence
   event payload seems to “lose” its transition type payload.

Comment: Better use a real device to test location stuff.

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail exactly the same issue here. Always getting a GeofencingEvent with a geofenceTransition of -1. Very annoying that it is currently not possible to simulate entering a geofence during development